# Dynamically adding polymer element which contains polymer-signals raises exception

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

With Polymer, I have implemented a custom form, which is using `polymer_signals.html` for listening to changes from arbitrary other polymer elements.

It is implemented like this:

```html
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/polymer_signals/polymer_signals.html">

<polymer-element name="user-settings" extends="form">
<template>
<polymer-signals on-polymer-signalauth-changed="{{onAuth}}"></polymer-signals>
...
```

This element is dynamically instantiated in a parent polymer element like this:

```dart
var userSettings = new Element.tag('form', 'user-settings');
$['main'].children.add(userSettings);
```

This raises the exception:

```dart
Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:4) of '_GrowableList'._notify@0x1c4cf589 (http://127.0.0.1:3030/buddy/web/packages/polymer_elements/polymer_signals/polymer_signals.dart:39:12)
<anonymous closure> (http://127.0.0.1:3030/buddy/web/packages/polymer_elements/polymer_signals/polymer_signals.dart:49:12)
```

If I statically instantiate the polymer-form, I don't get this error. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Cool you are using polymer_elements. Hopefully we will publish a new release soon (still a few issues to solve though). Sorry, I'm already too tired to investigate. I'll check tomorrow and answer then. At first sight it seems like a Polymer bug. It might be that a workaround is possible. I'll have to try a few things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem.

There are two common things that are often missed

1. if you have a custom `main` method
   see the answer to [Polymer querySelector working on DartVM but not in Chrome after compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932180)
2. call of `super.polymerCreated()` in the constructor of elements that extend DOM elements.
   see the answer to [Custom Polymer element extending AElement in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382832)

If you still can't solve the problem please add more code to your question (for example how your user-settings element looks like).

Comment: I will see if I can isolate the problem better. From the exception it looks like some concurrency issues, because I am having several instances of ```<polymer-signals>```. But only one is dynamically added.

Comment: I had it two times added statically and two times dynamically (one inside a normal polymer element and one in an polymer element that derives from a form element). Did you verify the points in my answer? I executed the code to add the elements dynamically in `main()` not in a method of another element. In which method is your `new Element.tag()` code?

Comment: I have done some more testing now. I have made sure to check your suggestions, but it is not the problem. I think the problem is because the code adding the element containing the ``<polymer-signals>`` is called when listening to an event fired by polymer-signal. Because polymer-signals is currently iterating all its listeners about an event, it fails adding another listener, because it does not have a concurrent protection. I tested adding my element outside of polymer-signals, and it works. It also works to wrap the creation of the new element within a Future, or after a delay. Bug?

Comment: I haven't ported this element and not used yet so my knowledge is limited. I agree with your reasoning. This was my first thought when I saw the code where the exception is thrown. But how can this be connected with the method you add the element? I guess a workaround would be to iterate over a copy of the `_signals` list.

Comment: Do you use a hosted release of polymer_elements or a clone from the GitHub repo?

Comment: The release is fetched with pub, so i guess pub.dartlang.org would be the host. Should I rather use the github repo?

Comment: I was thinking what is the easiest way to bring the workaround to you so you can test it. It would be cool if you could try the version from the GitHub repo.

Comment: I have checked the source on github now. I see your fix.

Comment: And does it help? :D I can't verify if it works because I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Your fix seems to work fine. Thanks! But I am skeptic towards my explanations based on what I see from the source, as I can't see the concurrent add and read issue. Every polymer-signal instance will define it's own list. --Just needed some time to test:)

Comment: Your comment is not entirely clear to me. Does it all work as expected now or do you still have some kind of issue?

Comment: The original problem with the exception is solved, because it now works without a delay or wrapping in a future. So yes, I consider it to be working. But, I now seem to have issues with actually catching a polymer-signal, which for now needs to be delayed. Might be related, but I have to investigate more.