# extendTag in Dart custom element

Tags: dart, dart-html

from [this link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#fromtemplate) in javascript, customs element extending button is made as:

```dart
var MegaButton = document.registerElement('mega-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
  extends: 'button'
});

<button is="mega-button">
```

I tried making the same using dart, by this code:

```dart
class MegaButton extends ButtonElement  {
static final tag = 'mega-button';
factory MegaButton()=>new Element.tag('button', tag);  
   MegaButton.created() : super.created() { 
       var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
       shadow.text='save';
  }
}
 document.registerElement(MegaButton.tag, MegaButton);
```

in the html file

```dart
    <button  is="mega-button"></button>
    <mega-button>click me</mega-button>
```

but got this error:

```dart
Exception: Unsupported operation: Class must provide extendsTag if base native class is not HTMLElement
```

any help pls. thanks

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: document.registerElement(MegaButton.tag, MegaButton); this is called in a separate function where I register all my custom elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.registerElement should look like:

```dart
document.registerElement(MegaButton.tag, MegaButton, extendsTag: 'button');
```

```dart
=> new Element.tag('button', tag);
```

see also [Custom Polymer element extending AElement in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382832)

Comment: did not work :( I do not want to use Polymer Custom element, just DART vanilla custom element. I adjusted the code in my question to reflect the code I've after your answer. is there some thing wrong in the item registration!

Comment: `Element.tag` is plain `dart:html`.

Comment: half done :), error msg gone, the var megaBtn = new Element.tag('button', 'mega-button'); worked with me, but neither <button  is="mega-button">click</button> nor <mega-button>click me</mega-button> worked.

Comment: You definitely need to use `<button is="mega-button">...`. As always 'didn't work' doesn't contain any useful information.

Comment: not getting you, can you elaborate more pls, based on my adjusted code. thanks

Comment: `<button is="mega-button">...` is the correct form to use such a custom tag and you should elaborate more. You wrote ` but neither <button is="mega-button">click</button> nor <mega-button>click me</mega-button> worked.` but you should define what you mean by `doesn't work`. Do you get an error message? Does the browser console print some message? Is nothing shown on the page? What does `inspect element` show? Does it show a `shadowRoot` element inside the tag you added? ...

Comment: The browser does not show any thing on page, and no error msg in the console! The element inspector shows: <button is="mega-button">#shadow-root "save" </button> <mrga-button>Click me</mega-button>

Comment: I guess you need to add a `<shadow></shadow>` tag to define where the content of the base class should be displayed.

Comment: sorry, there was something wrong in my CSS that was preventing it from being visible, your answer is correct. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked perfectly with me:

```dart
class SaveBtn extends HtmlElement  {
       static final tag = 'save-button';
       factory SaveBtn()=>new Element.tag(tag); 

    SaveBtn.created() : super.created() {
    //  Create a Shadow Root
    var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
   // Create a standard element and set it's attributes.
   var btn = new ButtonElement()
    ..style.height= '20px'  
    ..style.width= '50px'
    ..style.color= '#FF8F66'
    ..style.border='1px solid #BCC1C8'
    ..style.background='#F1F4FB'  
    ..style.borderRadius='5px'
    ..style.fontFamily='openSansItalic' 
    ..style.fontSize='12px'
    ..style.padding='0px 6px'
    ..style.marginLeft='0.1em'  
    ..style.borderBeforeStyle='solid'
    ..style.borderWidth='1px'
    ..style.borderColor='transparent'
    ..style.marginBottom='2px'
    ..style.borderBottom='1px solid #D1DBE9'; 

   btn.text= this.getAttribute('data-name');

   btn.onMouseDown.listen((e){ 
      btn..style.color="#333"
     ..style.background='#FF8F66';
    });
   btn.onMouseUp.listen((e){ 
   btn..style.color="#FF8F66"
     ..style.background='#F1F4FB'
     ..style.outline='none';  // remove the focus outline/glur
    });
   btn.onMouseEnter.listen((e)=> btn..style.boxShadow='0px 0px 5px #888888');
   btn.onMouseLeave.listen((e)=> btn..style.boxShadow='0px 0px 0px');

   if(btn.disabled==true){
     btn..style.color="gray";
   }
   shadow.nodes.add(btn);

   Element launchElement(){ 
     return (shadow); 
    }

  }  
 }
```

the custom element registration:

```dart
document.registerElement(SaveBtn.tag, SaveBtn);
```

and in the html file, I used:

```dart
<save-button data-name='save orders'></save-button>
```

Comment: It is perfectly fine when you add your own answer when it contains additional information but when the information I provide leads to the solution I expect at least an upvote especially when it not a trivial question.