# How can I create a new subclass extends a ButtonElement

Tags: dart, dart-html

1. import `dart:html` , I can create a new subclass `MyButton` of
   `ButtonElement` with factory constructor ,and add some new function
   such as `getButtonName(){}` ...
2. when it's running ,I get a instance

   ```dart
   MyButton btn=new MyButton()
   ```
3. But the instance "btn" runtime type is still `ButtonElement`, and can't call the `getButtonName()` function. If I use `btn as MyButton` then I get this error

   > **Uncaught CastError: Casting value of type
   >           ButtonElement to incompatible type MyButton**

Here is the code

```dart
    class MyButton extends ButtonElement {   
       factory MyButton(){
        return new ButtonElement();   
       }

       String getButtonName(){
        return "ButtonName";   
       } 
    }
```

Comment: Why a super class used a factory constructor ,then forced the subclass must use the factory constructor too ?  and the instance cannot access the static method of the class ? Why ?

Answer (score 1):

Just because this line

```dart
return new ButtonElement();
```

is within a factory constructor or `MyButton` doesn't mean it has any relation to `MyButton` it still returns `new ButtonElement()`.

This question [extendTag in Dart custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314402) shows how to create a custom element without Polymer.
See also this discussion https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/-z_8sVp_uPY