# On which version is based Polymer Dart?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

What the version Dart Polymer use (of the original Polymer project, eg 0.5 or 0.8 etc)? And where can I see it? I mean on which version Polymer.dart is based concerning the mainstream Polymer.js. For example recently Polymer (JS version) released 0.8 version with some breaking changes and features. I want to know when it will available in Dart version.

Comment: I think @Huey s answer is almost right. Just check the `CHANGELOG.md`. I think this is the best way to get the underlaying Polymer.js version. See for example the entry to version `0.16.1+3`

Comment: Good Gunter, thank you!) If you place it as answer I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an new Polymer.dart version is built on a new Polymer.js version they usually add the information to the CHANGELOG.md at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer

Polymer 0.8 will be available "soon" for Dart but as usual with Google they don't provide concrete dates.

Comment: (offtop) Gunter, please, could you consider the question when you have a time? I'm really stumble with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863293/polymer-dart-global-variables-and-data-bindings-observable.